# Dropdown Menu not working in IE

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, superfish

On a clients website ([HolidayHomes.ca](http://HolidayHomes.ca)) the dropdown menu doesn't appear to be working in Internet Explorer, not really sure how to go about fixing this..

It appears to have something to do with text-indent on the `ul li.inner` class. It was grabbing `text-indent: -2000px;` from `#nav li`, all of my submenu li's have the class `.inner`

I've tried adding `text-indent: 0px !important;` to `ul li.inner`, but it doesn't seem to be working? However I've noticed if I remove the `text-indent` from `#nav li` completely, it works fine?

Help is appreciated! I'm pulling a LOT of hair out over this.. and I'd rather fix it then have to install a new dropdown menu script completely... ugh.

Comment: i don't see no dropdowns in my IE8, and in IETester i see nothing in IE9 tab...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few more hours of troubleshooting, I was able to fix this error by removing `display: inline;` from my `#nav li ul` element. :)

Answer (score 1):

Which flavor of IE is having a problem.   In IE 8 and up you can turn on the developer toolbar and walk through the code (similar to firebug in firefox)

just pulled up the site in IE 8 and it appears to be working ok.  What is the problem you're having?

Comment: I'm running it in IE9. I had turned off the text indent temporarily, so the issue is up again for you to look at.

Comment: Still not seeing it, but re-reading your original question, look at the order in the CSS that the items are being called.   Keep in mind that attributes cascade down so just because you are saying li.inner doesn't mean it won't inherit attributes from #Nav li or something else.   Adding the same attribute with a different value won't always override that for some reason.   What you can do is add border: solid 1px 'some color' to each of the elements (use a different color) and see where the browser is rendering them.

Comment: Also IE developer tools has a trace styles option on the html inspector you can also use it to see what styles the element is inheriting.

Comment: I've now insured that the .inner class I'm trying to apply is at the bottom of the stylesheet. The dropdowns work fine if I actually remove the 'text-indent:-2000px;' from the '#nav li' .. but I can't do that as it shows the text then. Thanks for your help so far, really unsure what to do with this now. 

My IE version is 9.0.8112.16421, my clients is the same.

Comment: Looks like you're pulling in several style sheets.  I would run through these as well to see if there is something in a downline css file that is causing a conflict.  It could also be that something with a higher priority in the css is causing the issue.   You could try mocking up a page with just those navlink elements in it with the same css and see if it behaves the way you want it to there.   If so then you've at least eliminated that section as an issue.